# Código simple en Angular JS no funciona

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Este código no me funciona, ¿alguna idea?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{titulo}}</title>
    <script src="angular.min.js" type="text/Javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="miCtrl">
    <script>
    function miCtrl ($scope){

      $scope.titulo = "German";

    }

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: recibes algun mensaje de error en la consolta del browser ? a esta accedes con F12, en la sola console podras ver si hay algun problema. Como defines el codigo del controller?, podrias poner el codigo, recordaste agregar el tag script que referencia a los js del controller que defines

Comment: Como error principal me aparece esto:
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/ng/areq?p0=miCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
Gracias!

Comment: en que linea registras miCtrl al modulo de angular ?

Comment: Hola gracias por tu ayuda, como podrás ver soy nuevo con angular, este es todo el código que tengo. ¿Qué debería hacer?
Gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 2):

Te falta inicializar el modulo de angular y crear el controlador en dicho modulo:

```
var app = angular.module('appTest',[]);
app.controller('miCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.titulo = "German";

}])
```

Y debes apuntar a ese módulo al inicio:

```
<html ng-app="appTest">
```

Además, el controlador lo debes definir en el head para que reconozca la variable en ese `$scope`:

```
<head ng-controller="miCtrl">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>{{titulo}}</title>
  <script src="angular.min.js" type="text/Javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Te recomiendo que leas sobre los scopes en angular https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Comment: Perfecto. Muchas Gracias

Comment: @GermanCutraro Si eres nuevo an agular deberías saber que los controllers se inicializan usualmente en el tag `html` y en el `body`. En muy raras ocasiones se hace en el `head` como dice la respuesta ya que existen muy pocos casos de uso para eso. Saludos,

Comment: @devconcept Tienes razón, casi nunca se inicializan controladores en el `head`. Pero para el caso del ejemplo sirve para ilustrar hasta donde llegan las variables de cada controlador. Saludos.

Comment: @FreddyGarcia Sí, lo sé. Tu respuesta es correcta. La aclaración es para los usuarios que la consulten no copien el código tal cual sino que lo adapten a su problema particular. Saludos y muy buena respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

En el codigo veo que faltaria

[angular controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

algo como ser

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('miCtrl', ['$scope', miCtrl]);
```

Ademas el `<script>` deberias ubicarlo en el `<head>` debajo de la linea donde defines el .js de angular

Quizas ayude algo como ser

[An Introduction to Angular JS](http://callmenick.com/post/introduction-to-angular-js)

esta muy simple de seguir

Comment: Perfecto. Muchas Gracias